# input field validation using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a class "valid" to an input field if it matches the email and password criteria. I want to enable a submit button if both the fields have a valid class once the class valid is added it stays there even if the entered input is erased completely.

To fix this I have to either remove the valid class or increment the counter when the field is not empty. I'm trying the second case where I'm checking if the class valid is present and also if the field is not empty. I'm not getting the desired effect with the code below:

```
<input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" class="email required valid" id="aim_Email">
<input type="password" name="password" id="aim_Password" placeholder="Password" class="newpassword password required aimError" style="">


$('.required').live('blur', function (value) {
  if ($(this).hasClass('valid') && $(this).val()) {
    count++;
    if (count > 1) {
      alert('event fired');
      $(".submit").removeClass("disabled");
      $(C.options.currentPage).find('input[type="submit"]').removeAttr("disabled");
      $('.passwordHint').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Have you seen the html5 syntax for input attributes? See this http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to decrement the count once it is empty, you also need to limit the counts within the number of input fields. Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kswishaq/BKgGd/)

Answer (score 0):

The example is not complete as there is a reference to a `C.options.currentPage` and `count` is undefined.

With that said, I'm not sure what it is you're expecting, because it sorta works for me.  Check the jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UZFsD/).  I've modified your code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just check on each keyup event.  And use [toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).. as it allows for a condition to be passed in.. so if true it adds class.. if false it removes class

```
$('.submit').prop('disabled',true); // <-- disable button on load
$('.required').keyup(function() { // <-- bind keyup to both required inputs
    $('.required').each(function(i, v) { // <-- loop through each required field
            $(v).toggleClass('valid',$(v).val().trim().length > 0); // <-- add class if it has text
    }); 
    $('.submit').prop('disabled', $('.valid').length != 2); // button disabled if there's not 2 valid fields
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nxLeJ/3/